# Compiling the GKRocket demo without Provisioning and Code Signing

Tags: ios4

I understand the need to provision apps when you are getting close to deployment; however, right now, I am just trying to play with some sample code. Specifically, the GKRocket demo that ships with iOS 4.2 SDK. I want to compile and run it; however, I get the following error:

Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.apple.GKRocket' could not be found

The readme.txt claims "Build the game simply by opening it with Xcode and clicking on Build and Go."

I just read the following thread
[Code Sign Error When Building iPhone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269646/code-sign-error-when-building-iphone-application)

and the following
http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/index.action

Since the app is using the NSNotificationCenter, it leads me to believe that I need an AppID. But shouldn't the demo already be pointing to and AppID setup by Apple for the demo code?

The plist shows
Bundle identifier   com.apple.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

any ideas on what I should do to compile and run this in the simulator?

Update: 
I was able to get it running by code signing, but never could compile without it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears since the GKRocket Demo is using the NSNotification Center that in fact you need to sign your code. You can sign your code with your/or your team cert. Change the Project -> Project Settings -> Code Signing Identity to use your cert. Note: If you don't have your cert, and you paid the $99 dev license go through the steps [here](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action).

Then open the plist file and change the bundle to your domain name.

Also, to get the GKRocket Demo running, make sure you turn on Bluetooth in your network settings.

System Preferences -> Bluetooth. Turn it on and check discoverable. Then go into advanced settings [image: Advanced Bluetooth Settings]

Install your app on your iPhone with a build and run. Close the debugger. Then start your app in the local iOS simulator. Now manually run your app on your phone.