# Sample project from GitHub not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gpuimage

I'm trying to run one of the `GPUImage` sample projects (`FilterShowcase`) and I keep getting the following error:

```
Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.sunsetlakesoftware.FilterShowcase' could not be found
```

Usually I'm able to run projects I download from GitHub no problem, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Do I need to request the provisioning profile from the author? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269646/code-sign-error-when-building-iphone-application. I think it should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, somewhere along the line I deleted my team provisioning profile! Didn't realize it, but I was also unable to run any other sample projects that weren't created by me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the sample project has `com.sunsetlakesoftware.FilterShowcase` mentioned as it's Bundle Identifier, And there will be no Provisioning Profile in your system matching this bundle ID. So make sure you set the right Bundle identifier in the TARGETS / plist.

```
Do I need to request the provisioning profile from the author?
```

No, you don't need to request the provisioning profile from the author. You can use any provisioning file to run the app on the Device unless it's Bundle ID matches the Bundle ID specified in the TARGETS / plist of your app.

Comment: Thanks...what would be the right bundle identifier to set it to?

Comment: @StupidQuestionIKnow: If you have any provisioning profile on your system (and if your device is Added in that provisioning profile), just copy it's Bundle identifier and replace the "com.sunsetlakesoftware" in the Project TARGETS / plist with that bundle ID.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is most likely caused by Xcode.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758154/code-sign-error-provisioning-profile-cant-be-found) might help

Comment: This is not the answer he asked for- You are giving him wrong directions!